# Перемещение объектов с сохранением позиций

Tags: mysql, php, сортировка

Здравствуйте.

Хотел поинтересоваться, как же работает перемещение, например, объектов с сохранением позиций?

В качестве скрипта перемещения, использую плагин **Sortable**. Например я получил ним порядок id, которые переместил и они отобразились в таком порядке: `6, 8, 17, 24, 19, остальные значения...` и тем временем из базы данных получаю данные вообще по другой сортировке:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `tasks` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 24");
while($d = $db->fetch($q)) {
 echo $d['id'].', ';
}
```

которая выводит такие данные:

```
24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Но как же мне получить тот порядок, который получился в результате перемещения? Т.е такой:

```
6, 8, 17, 24, 19, остальные значения ...
```

Порядок при сортировке для теста я сохраняю в `$_COOKIE['tasks_sort']`;, но как и отсортировать ещё вывод из БД?

Если быть проще, то когда я перемещаю элементы, они сохраняют порядок, пока не обновишь страницу, ведь я никак не сортирую значения из базы данных на основе `$_COOKIE['tasks_sort']`, чтобы сохранение осталось навсегда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может помочь [FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field).

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tasks` 
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`,6, 8, 17, 24, 19, остальные значения ...) 
LIMIT 24
```

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, тут минус в том, если я добавлю через бд новую запись, то перестанет все работать. Придется и в куках ее айди дописывать. Это не дело...

Comment: @ModaL, не перестает. сортировка работает как надо. почитайте документацию по этой функции, в соответствии с ее поведением модифицируйте свой алгоритм. например:

    order by (`id`, ...,19,24,17,8,6) desc, id

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, нет. Если количество записей в tasks равняется например 50, а `$_COOKIE['tasks_sort']` содержит 30, то всё начинает работать криво. Зачем мне ставить desc, когда у меня всё зависит от значений в куках? то есть если на первом месте 3, то запись с айди 3, если на втором месте 144, то запись с айди 144, если на третьем месте 1, то запись с айди 1. Получается, если я начну юзать desc, то выйдет так: `144, 3, 1`, а не `3,144,1`

Comment: @ModaL, вы зачем спорите? попробуйте сначала сделать как написано. Да, порядок поменялся. ну и вы поменяйте. в ответе порядок `6,8,17`, в комментарии `17,8,6 desc`. Функция FIELD для значений, неуказанных в ее параметрах возвращает 0, поэтому новые айди у вас будут идти первыми, для совпавших значений id из указанного списка значения функции будут равны индексу в этом списке 1,2,3 и тд. сортировка будет идти в порядке 0 (для новых айди), 1,2,3,4 (для указанных в списке). Если вам нужно чтоб новые айди шли в конце, значит нужно инвертировать имеющийся список и добавить desc.